# SQL Server Query- How to Prune a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, apriori

I have a Table 'L2'

```
Itemset      Itemset2      
   1             3
   2             3
   2             5
   3             5
```

I created a [combination in pair of three] for these values in columns in table 'c3'

```
Itemset       Itemset2       itemset3
   1              3             5
   2              3             5
   1              2             3
   1              2             5
```

Like in Apriori I want to prune the table C3.

i.e. Getting this table as output 'C3Prune'

```
 Itemset       Itemset2       itemset3
   2              3             5
```

I want to create a SQL Server query for the same, I tried loops but it's not correct.

Comment: for me it's really unclear, I didn't understand, can you edit the question and tell more about the logic behind your last two result sets?

Comment: The 1st row in 'C3' has {1,3,5} so creating subsets of two {1,3},{1,5},{3,5} and checking if these subsets are present in 'L2', If yes than inserting it in 'C3Prune' else moving to the next row of 'c3' .
@Farhęg Thanks

Comment: `1, 2`   is not in L2, then why it is in result output?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I'm Sorry, I forgot to delete that row. Apologies. Amending the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @L2 TABLE ( I1 INT, I2 INT )
DECLARE @C3 TABLE ( I1 INT, I2 INT, I3 INT )

INSERT  INTO @L2
VALUES  ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 2, 3 ),
        ( 2, 5 ),
        ( 3, 5 )

INSERT  INTO @C3
VALUES  ( 1, 3, 5 ),
        ( 2, 3, 5 ),
        ( 1, 2, 3 ),
        ( 1, 2, 5 )


--Version 1
SELECT  c.*
FROM    @C3 c
        JOIN @L2 l1 ON c.I1 = l1.I1 AND c.I2 = l1.I2
        JOIN @L2 l2 ON c.I1 = l2.I1 AND c.I3 = l2.I2
        JOIN @L2 l3 ON c.I2 = l3.I1 AND c.I3 = l3.I2

--Version 2
SELECT  * FROM @C3 c
WHERE 
        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @L2 WHERE I1 = c.I1 AND I2 = c.I2) AND
        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @L2 WHERE I1 = c.I1 AND I2 = c.I3) AND
        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @L2 WHERE I1 = c.I2 AND I2 = c.I3)
```

Output:

```
I1  I2  I3
2   3   5
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways are provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29296401/3208640), I want to give another query with using of `UNION` and `EXCEPT`:

```
  select *
  from C3
  where not exists
  (
    select c3.itemset a, c3.itemset2 b 
    union
    select c3.itemset a, c3.itemset3 b 
    union
    select c3.itemset2 a, c3.itemset3 b 
    except
    select itemset a, itemset2 b from l2
   )
```

Output:

```
2   3   5
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/231eea/20)